# How to use soul with glossaries to space-out acronyms?

Tags: spacing, glossaries, capitalization, soul

I want to increase the spacing between capital letters of acronyms inside text. Acronyms are printed by `\ac`, `\acs`, etc. commands of the `glossaries` package. `soul` package provides a nice command `\caps`. How can I modify glossaries to use `\caps` for acronyms?

Here is an example that does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul} 
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries  
\newacronym{OFDM}{OFDM}{Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing} 
\let\acbak\ac
\renewcommand{\ac}[1]{\caps\acbak{#1}}
\begin{document}   
    \noindent 
    \ac{OFDM} \\
    \ac{OFDM} \\
    \caps{OFDM}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by `\caps` needing to have its argument fully expanded. Here's a solution that defines `\xcaps` that first expands its argument. You can then redefine `\acronymfont` to use `\xcaps`. I've used the custom style to provide the modifications.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul} 
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries} 

\renewcommand{\acronymfont}[1]{\protect\xcaps{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\CustomAcronymFields}{%
  name={\noexpand\acronymfont{\the\glsshorttok}},%
  description={\the\glslongtok},%
  first={\noexpand\acrfullformat{\the\glslongtok}{\noexpand\acronymfont{\the\glsshorttok}}},%
  firstplural={\noexpand\acrfullformat
    {\the\glslongtok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix}{\noexpand\acronymfont{\the\glsshorttok}}}%
  text={\noexpand\acronymfont{\the\glsshorttok}},%
  plural={\noexpand\acronymfont{\the\glsshorttok\noexpand\acrpluralsuffix}}%
}

\SetCustomStyle

\makeglossaries  
\newacronym{OFDM}{OFDM}{Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing} 

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\xcaps}[1]{%
 \protected@edef\tmp{#1}%
 \expandafter\caps\expandafter{\tmp}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}   
\caps{OFDM}

\ac{OFDM}

\ac{OFDM}

\end{document}
```

Here's a simpler solution that uses the [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts=ac]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand{\glsabbrvdefaultfont}[1]{\caps{#1}}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{OFDM}{OFDM}{Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \ac{OFDM} \\
    \ac{OFDM} \\
    \caps{OFDM}

\end{document}
```

[image: Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing (OFDM) OFDM OFDM]

Use a similar method if you want to combine it with a different abbreviation style. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts=ac]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand{\glsabbrvscfont}[1]{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\caps{#1}}}}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-sc}

\newacronym{OFDM}{OFDM}{Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \ac{OFDM} \\
    \ac{OFDM} \\
    \caps{OFDM}

\end{document}
```

[image: Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing (ofdm) ofdm OFDM]

Comment: thanks alot. It works fine, but `smallcaps` option changes `\acf` and first expnasion of acronyms if `first={}` option is used.

Comment: @Aydin I've changed the example to use the custom acronym style. If you want a different format you can modify the custom acronym fields as required.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Your simpler solution that uses `glossaries-extra` currently (up to date TL 2020) leads to the following error: `! Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 18.
<inserted text> 
                \fi`