# Highlighting error with acronyms and soulpackage within \hl

Tags: glossaries, soul

With the soul package and acronyms in this combination:

> \hl{\acrlong{SKO}}

there always comes an error like this:

> Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry `{SKO}' has not been defined. ...piel wäre hier das \hl{"'\acrlong{SKO}"`}

Is there a problem to use glossaries within the \hl{}?!

**Solution:** \hl{**\mbox{**"'\acrlong{SKO"`**}**} Just put a \mbox arround the acronym...

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102274/how-to-use-soul-with-glossaries-to-space-out-acronyms

Comment: I am not really sure if this fixes my error, but i will check later. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, i´ve "fixed" it with a mbox. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from "fixing" it with an `mbox`, you can also use `\soulregister` to register the `\acrlong` command. This will expand the command much like `mbox` does, but without having to change all occurrences in your document. Use

```
\usepackage{soul}
\soulregister\acrlong7
```

in your preamble to do this (cmp. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139500/223749 for a longer explanation including examples).